# Create an interactive map in iOS

Tags: ios

I need to create an interactive map in iOS.

I have to do a thing like [Expo app](https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/expo-milano-2015-official-app/id906490977?mt=8).

[image: Map Expo App]

An image or a map view in background and draw the way between 3-4 points.

I don't know if use Google Maps, Apple Maps, images or something else.

Answer (score 4):

Developing a spatially aware application is no trivial matter on any platform.  It will require careful planning and architecture design UP FRONT or you'll find yourself doing a lot of "extreme programming" (tons of refactoring).  In order to develop a spatially aware application you will need several items:

- **A familiarity with a map API.**  Apple's MapKit API is fine, but there are others such as **Mapbox** which offer additional services such as
  offline caching, custom basemaps, etc.
- **A custom basemap:**  The basemap you're seeing here is certainly a custom job and probably not open source, so you'll need to come up
  with one of your own.  Unfortunately, every map API has a different
  approach to this so you'll need to do some research to determine the
  right solution for your API.
- **Map features:** You'll need to understand how to add features to your map.  Some APIs call these Annotations, while others simply call
  them Features (like ESRI).  In either case, you will need to generate
  your own feature geometry using the **Core Location** API and whatever components the map API utilizes.  You will also need to create custom graphics for these annotations,
  unless you can find something suitable in the public domain.  If you
  intend to add polylines (for directions) or polygons (to highlight an
  area) you will also need to define your own custom symbology (line
  color, width, fill colors, etc).  Again, not every API uses the term
  symbology to describe these details but hopefully you get the idea.
- **Data storage:** You'll need to decide how you're going to store and retrieve data for the mapview. You can store everything online in a
  custom web service.  You could also use something like the **Parse** API
  if you don't have the resources for your own web service. 
  Alternatively, you could store everything locally in a **SQLite**
  database or using **Core Data**.  In either case, you will need to have a
  plan for querying the location data in an efficient manner.  SQLite
  supports **R*Tree** indices which are a good way to store a geometry's
  bounding box (envelope) information, but you still need to roll your own INSERT and SELECT queries.  Most likely you'll need to come up with some combination of the two.
- **Learn the language:** Overall, you absolutely must learn the language of the map APIs. Its vital that you are familiar with the
  language of spatially aware applications, including the fundamentals
  of location technology, if you intend to be successful in this
  project. I would suggest beginning to do some research into the iOS
  MapKit API, and maybe an open source solution like **Mapbox**. Learning **geoJSON** isn't a bad idea even if you don't intend to use it in your app.  It is very simple and could help you learn a lot about spatial technology very quickly.

As you can see, there's a LOT going on in a spatially aware application, and this list is just a starting point.  I am not trying to dissuade you from your goal, but just be aware that this isn't a "drag and drop" sort of project.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Now i'm going to study this problem, and i will see what to do. Thanks a lot!